# CSS transition duration with div doesnt work

Tags: html, css, transition, duration

I was trying to make a hover thing, until I hover the image, the image should change into another image.. I successfully did it until I wanted to make a transistion duration and I was really confused why it didn't worked..

```css
#Bild-Rechts {
    background: url(bilder/Hintergrund-2.jpg) no-repeat;
    width: 605px;
    height:886px;
    float: right;
}

#Bild-Rechts:hover {
    background: url(bilder/HintergrundHover.jpg) no-repeat;
    transition-duration: 2000ms;
}
```

```html
<section id="elektro_One">
    <div class="Box-Top"></div>
    <div id="Bild-Rechts"></div>
    <div id="Text-Middle-2">
        <h3>Wer sind wir?</h3>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata.</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: How doesn't it work, or how did you expect it to work?

Answer (score 1):

You would be better setting the transition on the main element rather than the `hover` psuedo-class.

See the below working snippet that uses images from placeholder.com:

```css
#Bild-Rechts {
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/150) no-repeat;
  width:      605px;
  height:     886px;
  float:      right;
  transition: background 2000ms;
}

#Bild-Rechts:hover {
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/200) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<section id="elektro_One">
  <div class="Box-Top"></div>
  <div id="Bild-Rechts"></div>
  <div id="Text-Middle-2">
    <h3>Wer sind wir?</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Edit following OP comment about Firefox**

Firefox doesn't actually support background image transitions because they are not explicitly defined in the CSS transitions spec.  You can explicitly see what is included [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/#animatable-properties).

There are some suggested work-arounds which include layering two elements on top of each other and then fading the top one out to show the lower one - not elegant but may be the only choice in this circumstance.

Comment: but for me it doesnt work..? I change the transition: background 2000ms; from hover to main.. still doesnt work

Comment: @JohannesMark Which browser and version are you using? This is working for me quite happily in the snippet in Chrome

Comment: I am using Firefox

Comment: @JohannesMark Regrettably, Firefox and IE don't support background image transitions because they are not defined in the CSS Transitions spec.  See my updated answer for a link to the information about that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which CSS property you want to transition too, not just the transition duration.

```
.div {
  background: ...;
  transition: background 2000ms;
}

.div:hover {
  background: ...;
}
```

Here is a list of properties you can transition:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

Answer (score 0):

you must move `transition-duration: 2000ms;` to

```
#Bild-Rechts {
    background: url(bilder/Hintergrund-2.jpg) no-repeat;
    width: 605px;
    height:886px;
    float: right;
    transition-duration: 2000ms;
}
```

and remove it from

```
#Bild-Rechts:hover {
    background: url(bilder/HintergrundHover.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

good luck and try good

Answer (score 0):

It's better to separate background attributes and set transition for unhovered selector

```css
#Bild-Rechts {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  float: right;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

#Bild-Rechts:hover {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000");
}
```

```html
<section id="elektro_One">
 <div class="Box-Top"></div>
   <div id="Bild-Rechts"></div>
     <div id="Text-Middle-2">
      <h3>Wer sind wir?</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata.
      </p>
      </div>
</section>
```